# La data me llega bien al controller, pero al pasar al modelo me da error

Tags: php, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Quisiera ayuda en esta parte por favor

Comment: 1. El código va _como texto, con formato_. 2. ¿Y el error? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Que error te da ?